# How does android send files over bluetooth (using "share")?

Tags: bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm working on a system that expects to receive a file over bluetooth from an android phone. Of course, I could write an app on the file host and devise my own protocol, but (at least for now) I'd like to use the built-in "share" functionality where one can share to a bluetooth device.

Is there some sort of "start", "this is a file" etc. protocol that android uses before sending a file? I'd like to know if anyone has already gone through this before I just go ahead and dump the binary data to figure out what it's saying (and if I need to acknowledge packets somehow).

Comment: I don't know specifically for Android, but since considering it works cross-platform, I'd expect it's already a standard protocol like [OBEX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBject_EXchange).

Comment: See Bluetooth File Transfer Profile (FTP), which uses GOEP (IrOBEX), which uses RFCOMM or L2CAP.